# Deploy spinnaker components to pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: spinnaker

I want to deploy Spinnaker components to private cloud (PCF). I want to know whether the following procedure works or it. Download spring-cloud-spinnaker-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar (mentioned in https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-spinnaker) and run it (on Linux machine), then deploy the Spinnaker components to required space from local host.
If this procedure works, what are the requirements of my system? else  mention the way to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring Cloud Spinnaker is the proper way to install Spinnaker components into a PCF setup.

Each Spinnaker module is installed with custom settings, some including resources (for example, clouddriver needs 4GB RAM + 2GB disk space), and Spring Cloud Spinnaker applies that.

Spring Cloud Spinnaker itself needs 8 GB RAM + 4 GB disk to operate properly. This is cited here => https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-spinnaker#running-spring-cloud-spinnaker. When run locally, that probably won't be a problem. Should you install it into PCF itself, that would be a critical setting.

If you run into issues with the installer, you can reach out for assistance at http://join.spinnaker.io/ on the #general channel.

Comment: Thank you Greg for the answer. What should I do if I have to install spring cloud spinnaker into PCF?

Comment: Pull down the JAR from http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-spinnaker, and cf push that JAR into your PCF environment. Then fill out its settings with the PCF instance's API URL, etc.

Comment: what should be the memory limit and disk limit of the application? should i bind any other service?

Comment: 8GB ram + 4GB disk. There is some other setting setting I'm still divining because it the Java build pack has had some update recently made that impacts memory usage.

Comment: I shall try to install Spinnaker from local machine then. What is Primary Account Name? And also can I link Jenkins later after deployment?

Comment: Primary Account Name is the logical name for that space as you'll see it inside the UI. Jenkins settings is for orca, so if redeploy orca later that's fine.

Comment: FYI: We are in the process of finding a community representative to pick up and run with Spring Cloud Spinnaker.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the information. Can you provide me with some reference, how to push artifacts (by polling) from Jenkins build to PCF with the help of Spinnaker.

Comment: what is 'Jenkins Name' in the Jenkins section? is it just a logical name that has be given to the Jenkins server which i have to link?